# form.valid() should not display validation text?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

With Jquery.validate `required` fields are showing popup validation on fileds (like below pic)
[image]

I like this and working fine.

But I check `!form.valid()` condition `Popup` disappearing and normal validation text is displaying (like below pic)

[image]

java script function

```
   <script  type="text/javascript" >

    var form = $("#form1");
    $('#<%=imgLogin.ClientID%>').click(function (e) {
        if (!form.valid()) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            <%=Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnLogin, "")%>
        }
    });
</script>
```

How to get back popup only when checking form validation.

Answer (score 3):

Those popups have absolutely nothing to do with the jQuery Validation plugin. That is HTML5 validation triggered by your HTML5 validation attributes.  Normally, HTML5 validation is disabled by the jQuery Validate plugin. If you're seeing popups, it means that you've failed to properly initialize the jQuery Validate plugin.

If you only want to see HTML5 validation popups (visual style and support depends on browser version), then you can not use the jQuery Validate plugin.

Alternatively, if you want to display the messages from jQuery Validate within tooltips, you'll have to properly integrate your own tooltip concoction or a plugin such as Tooltipster or qTip2.